# How to make a new session with customer id? PHP/Mysqli

Tags: php, sql

I have a login page which generates $_SESSION['username'] = $username. 
I want to create new session $_SESSION['id'] which stores customer's id not username and pass it to another page. 
I'm still learning so please make your answer understandable. Thanks

here's my login code

```
<?php
    require('dbConfig.php');

     session_start();
   if(!empty($_SESSION["username"])){ 
    header("LOCATION:index.php");
  }


    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username); //escapes special 
    characters in a string
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$password);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

      header("Location: index.php"); 
            }else{
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    }else{
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure session_start() is present is every page and add this in the session creation section of your code:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
```

under

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

I am asuming your "id" is called "id" in your table

You can use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

To check whats in your session

Answer (score 1):

First of all: try to use mysqli_prepare to query user, by passing variable directly into `SQL` code, you open your system to SQL Injection.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username=? and password=?"
  $password = md5($password);
  $statement = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'ss', $username, $password); //bind variables before execute sql command to prevent SQL injection.
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);

  $rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement);
  if($rows==1){
     $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
     header("Location: index.php"); 
  }
```

Also, you must include `session_start();` inside `index.php` in order to read SESSION variable on `index.php` page.

Comment: @CliAd: no problem, one more thing, consider using OO version of mysqi, it's less verbose and makes your code more readable.